# Chat message from Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Are there any PHP examples of how to send Facebook chat messages to friends of the user, through Graph API? I want users to be able to invite their friends to my site through sending them invite link, but this link should not be public.

I already have Graph API set up on my website, and I would like to send a chat message (i.e. an invitation link) using that authenticated user session. Is that possible?

If not, is there an alternative way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to send chat messages through the Graph API. Chat messages use [the XMPP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP). See [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) for details.

There does not seem to be any way at this time to send a private message through the Graph API; messaging is currently read-only, and posts to another user's wall are visible to anyone who can see the <s>victim's</s> target user's wall.

Answer (score 0):

maybe its possible since chat and inbox are the same:
check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/ therefor

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's Chat API is deprecated since Graph API and they suggest no alternatives for now.

However, you have a limited alternative to send messages (only from a page) to a user (this only applies to conversations between your page and a user and you can only reply to user-initiated conversations):

1. Using `/{page-id}/conversations` edge, get a list of conversations that currently exist for the page.
2. Then, you can `POST /{conversation-id}/messages` with `message` field on the request body to send a reply to this conversation.

For details and limitations, see [this Graph API reference page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/conversation/messages).

NOTE: The standard messages and inbox objects are read-only.

I'm sure there will be a new method for chat when they totally deprecate the old Chat API. They're working hard to deal with spam.